# Where to post an orthography question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Would a general question about orthography be appropriate for this forum or would it be more at home in linguistics?

Comment: In what language is the word you're trying to spell? And is it why a word is spelled some way or why it is pronounced some way? And instead of twenty questions, can you give us a better idea of the nature of your question..that might reduce our questions and we can tell you directly.

Comment: Questions about English orthography are fine here ([tag:orthography]); however, the standard conventions are a matter of general reference (e.g. *Capitalize the first letter of the first word of a sentence*) and the finer points are very often a matter of your editor's opinion (e.g. *[Always/Never] capitalize the 'D' in d'Artagnan when it is the first letter of the first word of a sentence*), so I would advise a thorough explanation of context and of references consulted.

Answer (score 7):

The general rule is that if the question is specific to English, it is fine here (subject to being on-topic and the other restrictions); if you could ask the same question in a different language and still get useful responses, it would be better on Linguistics.SE. But if you're uncertain, ask wherever you think most suitable: it *may* be migrated, but there is no charge for the service.

Answer (score 0):

Questions about orthography as an item of study (such as how to design one, the history of existing orthographies, etc) should indeed be asked at Linguistics.

Comment: Note: we have the tag [tag:orthography].

Comment: I don't know why this is getting downvoted. I'm not saying that questions about English orthography shouldn't be asked here, but that questions about orthography itself should be asked at Linguistics.se.

Comment: Maybe say that explicitly in your answer? I dunno.